# Conditional DateTime.ParseExact format

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I am parsing a date from a bank deposit report, and the format is like this:

```
Jul  9 2015
Jun 20 2015
```

Basically `MMM dd yyyy` except that the single digit day does not contain a leading zero. Is there a simple way to do conditional formatting in `DateTime.ParseExact()`?  Or will I have to pre-process the date string and either add the leading zero or remove the extra space??  Here is what works for the single digit day dates:

```
Dim dtDepositDate As DateTime
dtDepositDate = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "MMM  d yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

and obviously, `MMM dd yyyy` would work for the two digit dates, but would not work for the single digit dates with an extra space in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For single/double digit day part**

Use single `d` which is good for both single and double digits day value.

Having single `d` would effect the values if the `DateTime` is converted to `string`. As far as parsing is concerned, it will work for both single and double digits day values, like `01` , `1` , `11`, `20` etc.  The same is true for `M`, `H`, `m`, specifier for `Month`, `Hour` `Minutes` etc.

**For multiple spaces**

For multiple spaces use `DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces` in parsing.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("Jul  9 2015", "MMM d yyyy",
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
```

or  for double digit day part:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("Jun 20 2015", "MMM d yyyy",
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
```

Comment: Notice that the two digit day does not have the extra space in between the month name.  That is the dilemma... `MMM dd yyyy` works for one case, and `MMM  d yyyy` works for the other case, but neither works for both.

Comment: I am thinking I will probably just do a `strDate.Replace("  ", " ")` to remove the leading space if applicable.  That should solve my issue, I just was wondering if there is some way to handle this with the string format itself.

Comment: @dubstylee, no just modified my answer.

Comment: @dubstylee, to ignore extra white spaces use `DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces`

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for - `DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpace`.  I thought there might be a way to handle both scenarios.  Thanks!